# How to set the path from one Ubuntu server to another Ubuntu server?

Tags: server

I need to install `thingworx` in Ubuntu system. I have 2 systems.
I need to install `postgres` in one system and I need to install `thingworx` in another system. I have already installed `postgres` in one system. I need to set the path of the `postgres` in `thingworx` system (another system). I have attached the error message I have received when I installed `thingworx`.

[image]

How to set the path from one system to another in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not asking you to set the path to the other server, but to the location of `psql`. If you are running Ubuntu 22.04, this will be in a location like `/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin`.

Here is a series of steps that you can follow to ensure `psql` is properly part of your `$PATH`:

1. If `psql` is not installed, you can install it like so:

   ```
   sudo apt update 
   sudo apt install postgresql-client
   ```

   You can confirm it's installed like this:

   ```
   psql --version
   sql (PostgreSQL) 14.5 (Ubuntu 14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
   ```
2. Identify where `psql` is:

   ```
   locate psql
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** You may get a message saying that `locate` is not installed. Feel free to install it if you wish to use this command.</sup>
3. Create a link to `/usr/bin`:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/psql /usr/bin/psql
   ```

Now the system will be able to connect to PostgreSQL databases.